# How to use GROUP BY on two columns even if their values are swapped

Tags: sql, group-by, self-join

I recently ran into a problem where I have to group by 2 columns with similar values. The columns can swap values anytime but I still need to group them.

For example, consider there is a duo that completes certain tasks

```
COL 1   |  COL 2   |  COL 3
User 1  |  User 2  |  Task 1
User 1  |  User 2  |  Task 2
User 1  |  User 2  |  Task 3
User 2  |  User 1  |  Task 4
```

in the above example, User 1 and User 2 have worked together 4 times and have completed 4 tasks. I am using GROUP BY on COL1 and COL2 but it is grouping the first 3 results and is leaving out the fourth one because the columns have swapped values. How can I deal with this?

Comment: Make sure col1 user < col2 user. E.g least and greatest can be used.

Comment: what is you expected output looks like?

Comment: according to my requirement, the expected output should return a single row with the total number of completed tasks i.e. User 1   User 2     4

Comment: Are you using MySQL? (I saw the <mysqli> tag, which was later removed.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. get all possible combinations and take one condition based on userIds. I haven't handled null but if that's a requirement you can use `nvl` or `coalesce` and add a dummy value to handle the cases

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COUNT(TASK) FROM 
(
  SELECT COL1, COL2, TASK FROM users
  UNION
  SELECT COL2, COL1, TASK FROM users
)a WHERE COL1 < COL2 OR COL1 = COL2
GROUP BY COL1,COL2
```

Output:

```
User1 User2 4
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3bc317)

Answer (score 2):

You swap the two columns so that smaller value becomes col1 and the other value becomes col2, then group:

```
SELECT col1_new, col2_new, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
    CASE WHEN col1 <= col2 OR col1 IS NULL THEN col1 ELSE col2 END,
    CASE WHEN col1 <= col2 OR col1 IS NULL THEN col2 ELSE col1 END
) AS x(col1_new, col2_new)
GROUP BY col1_new, col2_new
```

If `CROSS APPLY` or lateral joins are not available then you need to copy-paste the expressions inside the select and group by clause.

Comment: this is an interesting approach. if you are not using SQL Server you can create 2 additional columns which are sorted and group by them.

Comment: Computed columns, yes.

Comment: It seems like OP is using MySQL. (Someone later removed the <mysqli> tag.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `least()` and `greatest()` to make sure col1 user < col2 user. Then `GROUP BY`:

```
select least(COL1, COL2), greatest(COL1, COL2), count(*)
from tablename
group by least(COL1, COL2), greatest(COL1, COL2)
```

Comment: This. This is brilliant. For others who come after me, in SQLite, the functions are `MAX(A,B)` and `MIN(A,B)`.